# Spark Dataset.groupBy().count() returns empty table

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `Dataset.where("theColumn == number")`, therefore there is no empty `theColumn` field. The Dataset is received from a Cassandra database and all the data is present.

`Dataset.groupBy("theColumn").count().show();` returns an empty table, though all the rows exist in the Dataset received from database.

What might be the problem? How to fix it?

I set `spark.default.parallelism` value in configuration but no change occurred. I don't have any other special configurations set.

I call the method in JavaDStream.foreachRDD and have `JavaStreamingContext` and `SparkSession` running.

---

SparkSession:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[4]")
                .appName(AppName)
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", ip)
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", port)
                .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
                .getOrCreate();
```

StreamingContext :

```
SparkConf sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]")
            .setAppName(AppName2)
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", ip)
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", port)
            .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfig , batchInterval);
```

groupBy() location:

```
logLines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

        javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("my_keyspace", "table_name", mapToRow(Table.class)).saveToCassandra();

        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "my_keyspace");
                        put("table", "table_name");
                    }
                }).load().where("theColumn == number").cache();

        ds.show(); // Prints a correct table.

        Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds.groupBy("theColumn").count().cache();
        ds2.show(); // Prints an empty table.
    });
```

---

`ds.count()` and `ds.dropDuplicates.count()` both return 0

Apache Spark version 2.2.0

---

Seems that problem is caused when both `JavaStreamingContext` and `SparkSession` are used together.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Can you open `spark-shell`, execute the queries and edit your question with the outputs. Can you also include `Dataset.count` and `Dataset.dropDuplicates.count`. What's the version of Spark?